# logoff only works on layout after 1 refresh/request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Im working on a log module for my application, I need it to close session if the same user login on a different PC (close the old session). That part works but when I redirect from my filter to the logout view, the logout view uses a layout, and that layout has a menu inside a if:

```
  @if (Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                <nav>
                    <div> 
                        @Html.Action("_menu", "Menu")
                    </div>
                </nav>
               }
```

So I expect logout view to be loaded without the menu, but when I run the application the menu is there, until something like a refresh page happens, then the menu is gone.

my logoff method:

```
        public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("sid")
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10) // Eliminar la cookie
        };
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);


        if (HttpContext.Session["errorMsg"] == null)//salida normal?
        {
            return RedirectToAction("LogOn", "Account");
        }
        else//no                         
        {
            //Session.Abandon();
            ViewBag.error = HttpContext.Session["errorMsg"];
            Session.Abandon();
            return View(); 
        }
    }
```